# Getting "msg: Failed to find required executable easy_install" when trying to bring up a vagrant instance with ansible

Tags: python, vagrant, ansible

One man. One mission. Configure a Vagrant machine with Ansible for use as a Python development environment.

I have attempted to provision a Vagrant machine with Ansible.

I set up my directory structure for it according to the instructions outlined here: 
https://danielgroves.net/notebook/2014/05/development-environments/

Everything went swimmingly, as shown in the initial part of the response to "vagrant up":

```
$vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: wa2_default_1413954520562_41027
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Available bridged network interfaces:
1) wlan0
2) eth0
    default: What interface should the network bridge to? 1
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8080 => 8080 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /home/useruser/proj/wa2
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible...
ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS='-o ForwardAgent=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s' ansible-playbook --private-key=/home/useruser/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key --user=vagrant --connection=ssh --limit='default' --inventory-file=/home/useruser/proj/wa2/.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory -vvv provision/playbook.yml

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<127.0.0.1> REMOTE_MODULE setup
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ForwardAgent=yes', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o , 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/home/useruser/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o', 'Port=2222', '-o', 'IdentityFile="/home/useruser/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'User=vagrant', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '127.0.0.1', "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413954587.93-167869388068052 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413954587.93-167869388068052 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413954587.93-167869388068052'"]
<127.0.0.1> PUT /tmp/tmpr8f2Xo TO /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413954587.93-167869388068052/setup
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ForwardAgent=yes', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/home/useruser/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o', 'Port=2222', '-o', 'IdentityFile="/home/useruser/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'User=vagrant', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '127.0.0.1', u"/bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413954587.93-167869388068052/setup; rm -rf /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413954587.93-167869388068052/ >/dev/null 2>&1'"]
ok: [default]

TASK: [easy_install name=pip] ************************************************* 
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<127.0.0.1> REMOTE_MODULE easy_install name=pip
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ForwardAgent=yes', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o , 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/home/useruser/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o', 'Port=2222', '-o', 'IdentityFile="/home/useruser/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'User=vagrant', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '127.0.0.1', "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413954593.04-227274886109270 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413954593.04-227274886109270 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413954593.04-227274886109270'"]
<127.0.0.1> PUT /tmp/tmptFp6Ev TO /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413954593.04-227274886109270/easy_install
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ForwardAgent=yes', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o , 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/home/useruser/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o', 'Port=2222', '-o', 'IdentityFile="/home/useruser/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'User=vagrant', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '127.0.0.1', u"/bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413954593.04-227274886109270/easy_install; rm -rf /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413954593.04-227274886109270/ >/dev/null 2>&1'"]
failed: [default] => {"failed": true}
msg: Failed to find required executable easy_install

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
       to retry, use: --limit @/home/useruser/playbook.retry

default                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1   

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

My directory tree is here: http://hastebin.com/qecudisuco.avrasm

Ultimately, the goal is to get set up for GAE work in Vagrant, with Ansible for automatic provisioning. (This may or may not be a good idea.)

```
failed: [default] => {"failed": true}
msg: Failed to find required executable easy_install

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/useruser/playbook.retry

default                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1   

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

How do I get Ansible to install pip on my Vagrant box?

Really any python provisioning will work.

I have read through the documentation or playbooks and easy_install.

For those worried about the lack of an inventory file, Vagrant creates one on its own. Vagrantup.com has a page on this, which I will post if I get the reputation necessary for it.

I'll go back through this question and revise it after I have thought about this a bit more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's trying to install pip by using `easy_install name=pip`. That's outdated, `easy_install` should no longer be used.

The current approach is to run `get-pip.py` (see [installation instructions](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html)). The command to run in Ansible is then `python get-pip.py`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'll try it out before I give it the green check-mark.

Comment: Works nicely, thanks.

If you are running with a user with restricted access, run `get-pip.py --user` and in Ansible, invoke with `pip: extra_args=--user`.

Comment: // . This worked for me, too. I especially recommend get-pip.py on systems on which you are allowed to run arbitrary Python scripts, like those run by Vagrant.

Comment: For some reason [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/easy_install_module.html) doesn't say a word about easy_install being deprecated.