# Ansible - Does easy_install module deprecated?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, vagrant

I'm provisioning a [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) box ([ubuntu/trusty64](https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64))  with [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/).

When executing the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: install pip
      easy_install:
        name: pip
        state: present

    - name: install gunicorn and flask
      pip: name={{ item }}
      with_items:
         - gunicorn
         - flask
```

I'm receiving the error below:

> Failed to find required executable easy_install in paths

Searching for a solution I found [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501086/getting-msg-failed-to-find-required-executable-easy-install-when-trying-to-br) which point on the fact that using `easy_install` is outdated.

I haven't found any hints in the Ansible [easy_install docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/easy_install_module.html).

Any help will be appreciated.

---

My Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
  end
end
```

Running with:

Ansible 2.7.10.

Vagrant 2.0.2.

---

Full Stacktrace of the error mentioned:

> TASK [install pip]
>
> ---
>
> fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find
>   required executable easy_install in paths:
>   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"}
>           to retry, use: --limit @/home/workspaces/python_flask/playbook.retry
>
> PLAY RECAP
>
> ---

Comment: `easy_install` is simply not installed on your base vagrant box.

Comment: ... or not found in the configured path. Although its an outdated method, the [module still exists](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/easy_install_module.html). If you have a recent box with python already installed, there are lot of chances pip is already there and you can skip your first task.

Comment: @Zeitounator, you're correct, it is not part of the core modules - my bad.
Can you post your comments as an answer and also mention this fact for others to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Simply transforming my comment as an answer.*

`easy_install` is simply not installed on your base vagrant box or not found in the configured path. Although it's an outdated method to install python packages, [the module still exists](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/easy_install_module.html).

If you install `easy_install` on your base vagrant box (either by rebuilding it or while provisioning with ansible as an `apt` task), the error will go away.

Meanwhile, if you have a recent box with python already installed (which seems to be the case), there are lots of chances `pip` is already there and you can skip your first task.